# Freemarker printing dates in different timezones

Tags: java, date, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker Version *2.3.20*.

I have a data structure where two dates are contained - one in *local time* and one in *utc time*.

```
// 2017-07-17 18:30 UTC
ZonedDateTime utcTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 7, 17, 18, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
// 2017-07-17 20:30 (+02:00)
ZonedDateTime localTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

Freemarker can handle only `java.util.Date` so I'm handing over dates.

```
Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapping.put("departureTimeLocal", Date.from(localTime.toInstant()));
mapping.put("departureTimeUtc", Date.from(utcTime.toInstant()));
```

In my template I would expect to write something like:

```
Departure (local): ${departureTimeLocal?string['HH:mm']}
Departure (UTC)  : ${departureTimeUtc?string['HH:mm']}
```

And as a result I would like to see:

```
Departure (local): 20:30
Departure (UTC)  : 18:30
```

What I see currently is:

```
Departure (local): 20:30
Departure (UTC)  : 20:30    <#-- timestamp interpreted in local time -->
```

I've also tried something like:

```
Departure (converted): ${(departureTimeLocal?string['yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'] + ' UTC')?datetime['yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z']?string['HH:mm']}
--> Departure (converted): 22:30
```

What would be the best way to archive something like that?

Yes I know: `java.util.Date` does not really have a timezone (only for printing) and `localTime/utcTime.toInstant()` both map to the same instants in zulu time.

Comment: One workaround would be `departureTimeUtc = utcTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));`

Comment: It would give the expected output, @Hugo, but we really don’t want a hack like that if there’s any way we can come up with something better…

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed, that's why I called it a "workaround". I don't use freemarker, so I don't know if it has some way to configure date formats

Comment: @morecore, I don’t know Freemarker. Would it work to put a string rather than a `Date` into your `mapping` map? Or would that too count as too much of a hack? What you really want to do is control how, in which time zone, Freemarker interprets the time of day of the `Date` object. No idea whether or how you may do that. And what you really-really want is that an upcoming version of Freemarker accepts `ZonedDateTime` objects…

Comment: I seem to understand from [the Freemarker reference](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html) that some changes in version 2.3.21 may help you. Would it be possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: Also [the page on the “setting” directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html) may be useful? I am just delving in without really understanding the text myself.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `iso_utc_m_nz` option, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Hugo The _trick_ using `withZoneSameLocal` indeed works - I've tried it before with `departureTimeLocal` witch shifted it in the other (wrong) direction, but did not used it with `departureTimeUtc`. But this has definitely as smell, as you already mentioned. And I did not used the `iso_utc_m_nz` correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With freemarker 2.3.20, you can use the [iso](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_date_iso) date built-in:

```
${departureTimeUtc?time?iso_utc_m_nz}
```

This built-in is deprecated since freemarker 2.3.21, and replaced by:

```
${departureTimeUtc?time?string.iso_m_nz_u}
```

The meaning of `iso_m_nz_u` is:

- `iso`: use ISO 8601:2004 format
- `m`: accuracy to the minute
- `nz`: no timezone
- `u`: use UTC instead of default timezone

A complete list of options can be found [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#topic.dateTimeFormatSettings).

Comment: Plain and simple, thx: `Departure (local): ${departureTimeLocal?time?iso_local_m_nz}` `Departure (UTC)  : ${departureTimeUtc?time?iso_utc_m_nz}`